# Stop installing python for each package by brew

Tags: macos, homebrew, python

I have installed python on Mac by Anaconda. Here is the path :

```
/Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

But when I want to install any package that need python, it installs it separately. For instance, I wanted to install the gdb (GNU Debugger) via **Homebrew**, but it said that python is one of the requirements and then it installed it again.

How can I stop downloading and installing python for every package?

Answer (score 1):

The nice thing about homebrew is it only installs dependencies needed to build the packages and also that you don’t have to choose just one version of a tool.

Why not let `brew` install what it needs, but control your path so that you’re running Anaconda from the python you prefer?

Also, brew has a cask install of anaconda as well, so that might be an easier path to harmony if you can’t get away from the homebrew installs for tools.

Comment: I mean that is that a convenient way to let the brew install python for each package?

Comment: Brew will install a python that it will then use for several other packages not a python for each package

Comment: But it doesn't. It installs a duplicate python that isn't needed, instead of using the one that is already installed.